# Is it possible to manage jira webhooks from plugin via Java API?

Tags: java, jira-plugin

I'm writing plugin for Jira and I need to manage webhooks from plugin code (read, add, edit and delete actions). I have found only one way to manage webhooks - REST API...  Question is simple: can I manage webhooks via Java API from my plugin? And if I can, how?

I've found this artifacts: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.atlassian.webhooks, but when I try to component-import some interfaces like com.atlassian.webhooks.spi.provider.WebHookRegistry my plugin does not start...

Comment: have you found a solution for this ?

Comment: Did you ever get this worked out? I am looking to do the same.

Comment: No. But i have stop my investigations on this question more than year ago.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you need to fire your code on issue create/update/delete. Then you need to write JIRA Event Listeners for appropriate issue events.
Here is tutorial: 
https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/Writing+JIRA+Event+Listeners+with+the+atlassian-event+Library

==================

Sorry, missed the point.
I am looking through the sources of jira-webhooks-plugin which is part of JIRA sources (and you get access to them when you buy any JIRA license) and do not see neither com.atlassian.webhooks.spi.provider.WebHookRegistry interface nor implementation.

I see that webhooks are created like this:

```
                final WebhookDao webHookDao = ao.create(WebhookDao.class,
                    new DBParam("LAST_UPDATED_USER", userManager.getRemoteUsername()),
                    new DBParam("URL", targetUrl),
                    new DBParam("LAST_UPDATED", new Date()),
                    new DBParam("NAME", name),
                    new DBParam("FILTER", filter.isPresent() ? filter.get() : ""),
                    new DBParam("REGISTRATION_METHOD", registrationMethod),
                    new DBParam("ENABLED", true),
                    new DBParam("EXCLUDE_ISSUE_DETAILS", JiraWebHookListenerParameters.ParametersParser.getExcludeIssueDetails(params)),
                    new DBParam("PARAMETERS", JiraWebHookListenerParameters.ParametersParser.getRemainingParameters(params))
            );
            webHookDao.setEvents(Iterables.toArray(events, String.class));
            webHookDao.save();
```

But probably you will not be able to execute this code in your plugin. Anyway, I advise you to loook into sources.

Please update me with your results.